# how to efficiently compress a 1025 byte json object

Tags: java, compression

I am trying to send a Json object (as a String) across a socket connection in java for a game I am making. This data is sent back and fourth very quickly (~30milliseconds per transfer) I don't have a whole lot of bandwidth, so I am trying to optimize my data transfer as best as I can.

here is what I have so far to take input and compress it (it also decompresses) this is my SSCCE I think thats the abbreviation?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String compressedString = compress("{"playerX":"64","playerY":"224","playerTotalHealth":"100","playerCurrentHealth":"100","playerTotalMana":"50","playerCurrentMana":"50","playerExp":"0","playerExpTNL":"20","playerLevel":"1","points":"0","strength":"1","dexterity":"1","constitution":"1","intelligence":"1","wisdom":"1","items":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"],"currentMapX":"0","currentMapY":"0","playerBody":"1","playerHair":"6","playerClothes":"7"}");
    System.out.println(compressedString);
    System.out.println(compressedString.length());
    System.out.println();
    String decompressString = decompress(compressedString);
    System.out.println(decompressString);
    System.out.println(decompressString.length());
}

public static String compress(String str) {
    String outStr = "";
    try
    {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) 
        {
            return str;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
        gzip.write(str.getBytes());
        gzip.close();
        outStr = out.toString("ISO-8859-1");

    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outStr;
 }

public static String decompress(String str) {
    String outStr = "";
    try{
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) 
        {
            return str;
        }

        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "ISO-8859-1"));

        String line;
        while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) 
        {
            outStr += line;
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e2)
    {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outStr;
 }
```

The String I am trying to compress is 404 characters roughly, and it gets compressed to 256. I was wondering if I could create my own charset of the alphabet and a few special characters, and use that instead of all ISO-8859-1

How would I use that newly created charset to compress the String I inputted in the main method speed isn't nescessarily an issue since I am only compressing very small String objects, as long as it doesn't take >200 milliseconds. bear with me this compression stuff is all very new to me, I am sorry if I sound ignorant.

If I try to just use ASCII instead of ISO-8859-1, the string will compress but it will not decompress and throws ZipException - not in GZIP format

Comment: Have you considered using your own binary encoding, instead of JSON?  If you are really fighting for bytes that may be your best option

Comment: could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

If your JSON objects are similar from transaction to transaction, you could consider using previous objects as a dictionary for compression for the next object, where those objects are also retained at the other end to use as the dictionary for decompression.  See the [setDictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#setDictionary%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method.  You can fill up to 32K of dictionary with 32 of your objects (sans a few bytes).

Comment: this is definitely what I am looking for. could you provide an example of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the bandwidth to spare for JSON, and your codebase isn't changing to much, you may want to use your own binary encoding using [DataInput/OutputStream](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_dataoutputstream.htm)